# REST: I don't get it

Tags: php, rest, service

I'm trying to understand and setup a REST service, but something's not clear to me.

On [this site](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) the following is said:

> let’s take a look at what some possible requests could mean: GET
>   request to /api/users – List all users. GET request to /api/users/1 –
>   List info for user with ID of 1

How to set this up? Is /api/users/1 a file in a folder? If not, how does this work then? When I will browse to api/users/1, I will get a 404 error, won't I?

[edit] For my application, I was advised to use a REST service with AJAX.

Comment: So you want to implement it using PHP? Please add the tag.

Comment: That is server configuration. Look for `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. There are tons of existing questions with helpful answers. Please use the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a server side language and a web server. This allows you to configure virtual folders or routes that will respond to particular client requests. Depending on the server side platform and language you are using there are different techniques to achieve that. For example if you use [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) you can configure the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when you send a request to `/api/users` it will be the `Users` action on the `Api` controller that will get executed and passed null as `id` parameter. And if you request  `/api/users/1` it will be the `Users` action of the `Api` controller that will get executed and passed 1 as the `id` parameter.

None of the files `api` nor `users` actually exist on the server. It's the routing engine that intercepts the request and dispatches it to a corresponding server side handler.

And here's [an article](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) you may take a look at which explains how to achieve that with PHP.

Comment: So I was advised to use a REST service with AJAX to do this server side (with php/javascript). How would that change things? Googling 'setup rest service ajax' (and other queries like that) does not yield useful results.

Comment: @Niek, once you setup the server side part, you could write any kind of client to this REST API. Javascript is just one example that will allow you to consume this API. You may take a look at some popular framework such as jQuery which makes it very easy to perform AJAX requests in a browser agnostic manner.

Comment: The quote I mentioned is from that article, actually. It provides a file with how to handle REST requests, but not how to use this file. And that problem occurs for me on every site I find..

Comment: @Niek, you could use AJAX. Are you familiar with AJAX?

Comment: Not really, no. I'm familiar with Java ('Normal' and Android) and a little php. I'm just beginning in trying to get a little experience in this stuff.

Comment: @Niek, well, if you get into web development it is actually recommended to learn javascript and AJAX. But if you are familiar with Java you could write a REST client using Java that will simply send HTTP requests to the given url and do something with the results. Almost any language could be used to write a REST client. Depending on your specific requirements you could pick one technique or another.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7147/discussion-between-niek-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 1):

This article supposes that the requests are mapped to a web application that can handle the URL-s as needed. For example if you use Java (and JAX-RS), you can map `/users` to one of your servlets, and you get sub-URL parts as parameters in your handling method. See this article to grasp the point: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

```
@Path("/users/{username}")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This answer was added before the question was tagged PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works for example with .htaccess files for Apache, which rewrite and reroute URl's (with mod_rewrite).

Check [mod_rewrite](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite) for further information.